# get length of an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int grades[100];
int j = 0;
int len = sizeof(grades)/sizeof(grades[0]);
while (j < len)
{
   cout << grades[j] << endl;
   j++;
}
```

I have entered only 5 grades and I want to print only that entered grades then ho can I print that?
I have tried to use length of array but since I have created array of size 100, it is printing all unwanted characters at the end.
I have also used '\0' to get end of array but it is not working.

Comment: Where do you read values into the array?

Comment: I have read value in grades[i]. The code I have not included. I only want to print entered grades

Comment: A plain C/C++ array doesn't keep track of the number of entries.
If you like to have that functionality I propose you use std::vector<int> instead

Comment: Your array has `100` elements, period. You need a separate variable to keep track of the number of "entered" elements.

Comment: @CodeWithFaraz please include all your code and make a [mcve].

Comment: `len` is always 100.

Comment: That I don't know. I only know basics. Is there any simpler way to do the same functionality? @PepijnKramer

Comment: How do you get the values in grades[i]? It matters since it might help to deduce the needed length.

Comment: @LearningMathematics user input grades by using while loop until user don't want to enter grades

Comment: Yes that's what we need, can you post the relevant code?

Comment: The simplest way is to use std::vector<> that is the proper dynamic array in c++

Comment: @CodeWithFaraz learn the standard library, it will avoid a lot of bugs in future code. 
However you could always add an extra integer that you keep track of yourself and increase by one each time you add an entry

Comment: @CodeWIthFranz I've noticed that most books haven't really been updated for 20 years and still teach 'C' instead of c++

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> grades;

// add 3 grades
grades.push_back(4);
grades.push_back(1);
grades.push_back(9);

// https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/
auto size = grades.size();
```

Answer (score 4):

Just keep track of the size when you read the numbers:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int const max_len = 100;
    int arr[max_len];
    
    std::cout << "Enter numbers: ";
    
    int len = 0;
    
    while (len < max_len && std::cin >> arr[len]) {
        ++len;
    }
    
    // you've read `len` numbers.
    
    std::cout << "You've entered " << len << " numbers\n";
    
    for (int i = 0; i != len; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code returns the total number of elements the array can store.
Try this instead:-

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int sample[10];
    int length = 0;

    for (int integer : sample)
    {
        if (integer != NULL)
        {
            length++;

            // If you want to print the element as well -
            std::cout << integer << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially what it does goes through all of the elements of the array and adds 1 to length if that element is not NULL (NULL means a null pointer, or if you're a beginner, just know it means basically nothing).

- You can easily change int to any other type.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: “NULL” does not mean nothing, it means a null pointer constant. Your code, if it compiles (and it’s not guaranteed to) will read until the first zero value (and will invoke undefined behavior if there is no zero in the array).

Comment: I said in simple language. My tutor first said me that NULL means nothing then when he taught me pointers and stuff, then he told me that.

Comment: You should show your tutor this code, and ask him whether it makes sense to compare an integer with NULL. I think he might be able to explain to you why this code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You've posted a couple of answers which show an admirable desire to help people, but which do not show the sort of expertise those people need to have their questions answered. You should concentrate on building up your own skills in C++. That will be the best way for you to help other people with their learning.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I am not a C++ expert I am still learning. BTW thanks for suggesting. But the answer overall still works just fine.

Comment: It really doesn't work fine. Try initializing `sample` to `{1,2,3,0,5,6,7}` and see what happens.